# Varnish 4 not allowing login to Drupal 7 when returning pass, only when returning pipe

Tags: wordpress, drupal, drupal-7, varnish, varnish-vcl

Our server hosts several Apache virtual hosts, some are Drupal sites and some are Wordpress sites. I've recently installed Varnish 4 and have it configured correctly and it's working great as far as I can tell EXCEPT that the return (pass) isn't behaving as I'd expect. Consider this bit of code below where www.foradacopa.com is the ONLY virtual host for which I'd like to have Varnish cache:

```
sub vcl_recv {    
  if (req.http.host != "www.foradacopa.com") {
    return (pass);
  }
# More stuff happens after this, but as I understand it should only apply to
# www.foradacopa.com requests, right?
}
```

With this in the VCL config file, I'm unable to login to www.pickupamerica.org which is a Drupal site. Instead I get results similar to this: https://www.drupal.org/node/891346. Examing the headers of the login POST response, there is no Set-Cookie (which there usually is) and the response is not from cache. Does Varnish alter headers or content when you return pass by default? Is there somewhere else in my VCL config that I should look for the stripping of this header? What exactly happens after you return pass? Shouldn't it just pass the request to the backend and return the backend response without alteration?

Below is the full VCL config file where we return pipe instead of pass and we are able to login. Is this is an acceptable solution security and performance wise?

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}

acl purge {
  "10.0.1.100";
  "10.0.1.101";
  "10.0.1.102";
  "10.0.1.103";
  "10.0.1.104";
}

sub vcl_recv {    
  if (req.http.host != "www.foradacopa.com") {
    return (pipe);
  }

  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    return (lookup);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
  }

  if (req.url ~ "\?(utm_(campaign|medium|source|term)|adParams|client|cx|eid|fbid|feed|ref(id|src)?|v(er|iew))=") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
  }

  if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php") {
    return (pass);
  }

  if (req.http.cookie) {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "(wordpress_|wp-settings-)") {
      return(pass);
    } else {
      unset req.http.cookie;
    }
  }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  if ( (!(req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin)|login)")) || (req.request == "GET") ) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 1h;
  }

  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 365d;
  }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
# multi-server webfarm? set a variable here so you can check
# the headers to see which frontend served the request
#   set resp.http.X-Server = "server-01";
   if (obj.hits > 0) {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
   } else {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
   }
}
sub vcl_hit {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    purge;
    error 200 "OK";
  }
}

sub vcl_miss {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    purge;
    error 404 "Not cached";
  }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    # http://www.varnish-cache.org/ticket/451
    # This forces every pipe request to be the first one.
    set bereq.http.connection = "close";
}
```

Any other tips for running both Wordpress and Drupal sites on the same backend with Varnish in front of it whilst still allowing logins would be fantastic as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flow chart helped me understand what's going on: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleDefault.

Essentially, after calling return pass, the request passes through vcl_pass, vcl_fetch and vcl_deliver. In my VCL config, cookies were being stripped out in vcl_fetch and now that it's clear the a pass will flow through there, I see why I cannot login.

It would still be great to understand whether returning pipe makes more sense than returning pass in this case. Also, VCL config wisdom for Wordpress + Drupal very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You should at least pipe when you notice a Drupal or Wordpress login cookie.  But often the developers demand a complete hands off by Varnish, for Drupal and Wordpress sites.  After all, these tools have their own caching system.